# Comments App within Modal - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently building an AngularJS picture gallery. I've successfully grabbed my images from flickr and displayed the data via ng-repeat. Next I got the UI Bootstrap to pop a modal up when the user clicks on the image to display a close up of the image in one half of the modal, and the users info on the right side.

I'm hoping of adding a commenting feature to each modalInstance, so users can comment on the pictures.

I'm building this angular app ontop of Shopify and was wondering, not for any code suggestions, but more of a "what would you do"/"point me in the right direction." How can I make each comment independent of others, etc.

Comment: You would use a backend - give each picture an ID and then save comments referencing the correct picture.